# Real-time user messages with Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, broadcast, long-polling

I really need some help, as well as examples for this issue. I need a conversation system on my site like Facebook (send message to conversation and load messages without page refreshing). I think there are many ways that this problem can be solved: broadcasting, long-polling or simple AJAX. It would be greatly appreciated if I could have an example using broadcasts. Below is what I have come up with to try to implement this.

**Table `conversations`**

```php
Schema::create('conversations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_one')->unsigned()->index()->comment('Sender ID');
        $table->foreign('user_one')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('user_two')->unsigned()->index()->comment('Inrerlocutor's ID');
        $table->foreign('user_two')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Table `messages`**

```php
 Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('message')->comment('Message text');
            $table->boolean('is_seen')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('deleted_from_sender')->default(0);
            $table->boolean('deleted_from_receiver')->default(0);
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index()->comment('Sender ID');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('conversation_id')->unsigned()->index()->comment('Conversation ID');
            $table->foreign('conversation_id')->references('id')->on('conversations')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**Controller**

```php
public function sendMessage($id, SendMessageRequest $request)
{
    if ($id == Auth::id())
    {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    $conversation = Conversation::whereIn('user_one', [Auth::id(), $id])
        ->whereIn('user_two', [$id, Auth::id()])
        ->first(); // Get conversation data

    /**
     * Create a new conv. when doesnt exists
     */
    if ($conversation == NULL)
    {
        $newConversation = Conversation::create([
            'user_one' => Auth::id(),
            'user_two' => $id,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create message
     */
    Message::create([
        'message' => $request->get('message'),
        'user_id' => Auth::id(),
        'conversation_id' => $conversation !== NULL ? $conversation->id : $newConversation->id,
    ]);

    return redirect(route('mails.chat', $id));
}

/**
 * Chat History
 */
public function chat($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id); // Get user data
    $title = 'Диалог с ' . $user->name . ' ' . $user->lastname; // Page title

    if ($id == Auth::id())
    {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    $conversation = Conversation::whereIn('user_one', [Auth::id(), $id])
        ->whereIn('user_two', [$id, Auth::id()])
        ->first(); // Get conv. data

    $messages = '';
    if ($conversation !== NULL)
    {
        $messages = Message::where('conversation_id', $conversation->id)->paginate(30); // Get messages
    }

    return view('mails.chat', [
        'title' => $title,
        'conversation' => $conversation,
        'messages' => $messages,
        'user' => $user,
    ]);
}
```

**Model Conversation**

```php
    class Conversation extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'conversations';
    protected $fillable = ['user_one', 'user_two'];
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

**Model Message**

```php
    class Message extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'messages';
    protected $fillable = ['message', 'is_seen', 'deleted_from_sender', 'deleted_from_receiver', 'user_id', 'conversation_id'];
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }

    public function conversation() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Conversation');
    }
}
```

**View**

```php
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

{{-- Simple display messages --}}
@if ($conversation !== NULL && count($messages) !== 0)
    @foreach($messages as $message)
        @php($sender = App\User::find($message->user_id))

        <div>
            <b>{{ $sender->name }} {{ $sender->lastname }}</b><br>
            {{ $message->message }}
        </div>
    @endforeach
@else
    <div class="alert alert-info">No messages.</div>
@endif

<form id="submit" method="post" action="{{ route('mails.sendMessage', $user->id) }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <b>Message:</b><br>
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>

    <button type="submit">Send!</button>
</form>

@endsection
```

Thank-you for assisting me with this.

Comment: There is also HTML5 Server-Sent Events if you are going to ignore MS Edge

Comment: Google "laravel chat application"

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr This did not help me. Just made it worse :c
There are no examples of implementing private chats.

Comment: Did you try: https://github.com/dazzz1er/confer

Comment: @nathan6137 Thanks for your answer. I would like to use an application that will work inside the site, without using third-party services (like Pusher). Unfortunately, it supports only 100 users, on a free tariff plan...

Comment: @MyZik Well, how about this: http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-52-chat-message-module-using-socketio-redis-express-and-nodejs-from-from-scratchexample.html there is even a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-BNl_YfrvE

Comment: @nathan6137 that solution looks really good. But I have some problems. How can I use commands like "sudo apt-get install redis-server" on Windows 8.1?
I have installed NodeJS for Windows

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [Laravel Echo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo). This will work well with redis server, socket.io and [laravel echo server](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting). It's really nice and easy to setup. Check out example application [here](https://github.com/xparthxvorax/Laravel-Realtime-Chat)